# Passing an array as a parameter using pyscopg2

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameters, psycopg2

Suppose I have PostgreSQL function that take the following parameters:

```
append_my_job_batch(project_type character varying, input_list text[], requester character varying)
```

I can run this function in PostgreSQL like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM spg_app.append_spg_job_batch('PROJECTNAME123', 
    array['1021', '1025','1026','1027'], 
    'myemail@gmail.com');
```

The above works without any issues. I am now trying to run this function in a Python script using the `psycopg2` module.

```
import psycopg2 as ppg
from typing import Dict

def run_stuff(credentials, product_name: str, my_array: list, email: str):
    with ppg.connect(**credentials) as connection:
        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM append_my_job_batch(%s, %s, %s);""", (product_name, my_array, email)) 
            connection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
        except Exception as e:
            raise ppg.DatabaseError(
                "Failed to run due to the following: {}".\
                     format(e))
    return result

###run function
some_ids = ['1021', '1025','1026','1027']
stuff_ran = run_stuff(credentials=my_credentials, product_name='MyProduct', my_array=some_ids, email='jjones@gmail.com')
```

When I run the above in the debugger, it generally kicks me out to the Exception as e, complaining about the structure of the original PostgreSQL function:

```
Exception has occurred: DatabaseError
Failed to run due to the following: column "request_datetime" is of type timestamp without 
time zone but expression is of type text
LINE 2:    SELECT * FROM spg_app.append_spg_job_by_type_aoi
              ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO temp_table(id, inventory_id, status, request_datetime, start_datetime, end_datetime, server_hostname, s3_folder, max_threads, retries, file_name, other_file_name, email, priority)
        SELECT * FROM append_another_job
            (
            $1,
            $2, 
            $3)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function append_my_job_batch(character varying, text[], character varying) 
line 25 at EXECUTE
```

My guess is that there is something wrong with how I am passing my parameters using `psycopg2`; probably the some_ids, not the format of the request_datetime. Any clues as to what may be going on here?

Note: The above error mentions that request_datetime is getting passed as text. On line 25 of my create script for the function, I am creating request_datetime like this:

```
request_datetime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
```

Comment: Try this `""", (product_name, [my_array], email),)` at the end of your `cursor.execute`

Comment: That looked promising but still throwing the same error.  If I run the Postgres function in PGAdmin using the same parameters, it works just fine. No complaint about the request_datetime.

Comment: then debug printing the query that will be executed with `print(cursor.query)` to see exactly what is going to be executed.

Comment: It is returning the following: `b"SELECT * FROM append_spg_job_batch('MyProject', ARRAY['321448','321754','322223','322225','322112','321838','321858','321860'], 'myemail@gmail.com');"` The only issue might be the `b` at the beginning, maybe?

Comment: No, that's the way psycopg passes queries to execute as byte literals b'..' Execute the above query in your database.

Comment: In python your select statement is missing the schema name as shown in your example `SELECT * 
FROM spg_app.append_spg_job_batch('PROJECTNAME123', 
    array['1021', '1025','1026','1027'], 
    'myemail@gmail.com');`

Comment: You show three functions `append_my_job_batch` and `append_spg_job_batch` and from the error `append_spg_job_by_type_aoi`.  Which is the correct one? We need context for `request_datetime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()`. Where is it defined in the function?

Comment: Hey All - I was able to track down the problem and fix it. It actually seemed to be caused by a formatting issue in an underlying PostrgreSQL function which is beyond the scope of my question. I'll close this out so not to cause confusion.